# SpringMVC 400 Bad request JSON data

Tags: json, spring, http, spring-mvc

I have some problem with sending request to spring mvc controller.
I have got entity:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;
    //..getters setters

}
```

and SpringMvc controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/companies")
public class FirmaController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
    public String addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return "person";
    }
}
```

When i would like to send request to server with curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -HContent-Type:application/json  -HAccept:application/json http://localhost:8080/api/companies/addPerson -d "{ 'name': 'Gerry', 'age': 20, 'city': 'Sydney' }"
```

i have got a **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 1392
Server: Jetty(8.1.10.v20130312)
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is correct:

```
curl -i -X POST -HContent-Type:application/json  
 -HAccept:application/json
 http://localhost:8080/api/companies/addPerson 
 -d '{ "name": "Gerry", "age": 20, "city": "Sydney" }'
```

Comment: I just see that you have added double quotes to key value pairs of JSON data, have you done anything else to make it work?

Comment: No. Only double quotes on key/value

Answer (score 5):

The data you send is not valid JSON. Strings have to be wrapped in double quotes `"` not single quotes `'` like in your example.

If you don't have an old version of Spring you should use  `consumes = "application/json"` instead of `headers=...`.

Comment: I disagree with you. Single quote is also correct one.
I tried with " and \" (with escape character and it is the same problem;/

Comment: @PiotrSobolewski The [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says otherwise. JSON names are wrapped in double quotes `"`.

Comment: Are you using jackson mapper dependency?

Comment: Hi. What are you trying to return from this method?